# Is there any way to expose iOS data protection as a user setting?

Tags: ios, keychain, entitlements

I want a users (or the organization ) to set the policy for my app, since I don't know their security requirements.

[image]

**Question**

- What is special about the iOS data protection setting such that it is only defined between the developer and apple?
- Is there any way I can have equivalent security for the end user to choose from?  (aside from publishing multiple apps)

Comment: You could provide a setting that you then use to set the security on the keychain items you create, but you can probably work out the appropriate setting with a few questions to yourself. Is your app a VoIP app that need to access keychain data when the device boots and potentially before the user unlocks? Set it to always. Does your app need to access data or keychain in the background?  If so, set it to after first unlock. If not, set it to when unlocked.

Comment: @Paulw11 My hope is that the end user or corporation can decide if the risk is too great vs the features.  This decision, would by its nature, disable functionality or make some apps simply not work.

Comment: So you would normally ask the user if they wanted to store their login details or whatever rather than asking about data protection classes which is rather technical.  Regardless though, as I said, you can easily ask the user what they want to do and then respond accordingly in your app. You just need to write the code.